# Initialization with tuple keyword vs parenthesis in python

Tags: python, syntax, tuples, standards, readability

This question is about design and readbility, not performance:

Is it more pythonic to initialize tuples with the tuple keyword, or just with parenthesis? Both do the same thing, but explicitly typing `tuple` is more verbose.

Here's two different cases of tuple initalization.

1. From existing iterable

```py
def myfunc(myarg: Iterable):
    # "tuple" is explicitly typed out
    mytuple = tuple(myarg)
```

```py
def myfunc(myarg: Iterable):
    # "tuple" is not explicitly typed out; only parenthesis are used
    mytuple = ([myarg])
```

2. Creating new tuple from literal

```py
# "tuple" is explicitly typed out
mytuple = tuple([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

```py
# "tuple" is not explicitly typed out; only parenthesis are used
mytuple = (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Contradictorily, I know that it is more common to initialize lists without explicit;y typing `list`:

```py
mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4] # "list" is not explicitly typed out; only brackets are used

# Rather than:
mylist = list([1, 2, 3, 4]) # "list" is explicitly typed out
```

Personally, I always explicitly type out tuple to make it easier to see that a tuple is being initialized. However, this contradicts my style (which is the more popular style) of initializing lists (without explicitly typing list.

In conclusion, I want to know which way of initializing tuples is more pythonic.

Comment: `list[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not valid Python syntax

Comment: Plus, `tuple(1, 2, 3, 4)` doesn't do what you think it does. You need `(1, 2, 3, 4)`. It's not a matter of style; it's a matter of actually having code that works.

Comment: `(myarg)` doesn't define a tuple at all; it's just a parenthesized expression, so `mytuple` is assigned whatever value was passed to `myfunc` in the first place: could be a list, a tuple, a dict, a generator, anything that is considered iterable.

Comment: @Woodford It's valid syntax; it's *symmantically* invalid in older versions of Python betcause `type.__getitem__` isn't defined and `list.__class_getitem__` wasn't introduced yet. As of Python 3.9, `list[1,2,3,4]` simply ignores the tuple in the brackets and returns `list` itself.

Comment: @chepner: Well, no, it creates a `types.GenericAlias` instance.

Comment: Repeat to yourself: *parentheses don't define tuples*. A tuple is defined by an expression list, which is simply a sequence of expressions separated by commas. Parantheses are only necessary to disambiguate *this* use of commas from other uses of commas. The only exception is the empty tuple `()`, since empty parentheses don't otherwise have an established meaning.

Comment: @user2357112 True; at runtime, though, it behaves like `list`.

Comment: They are not, in fact, equivalent.

Comment: @Woodford I'm not sure what 2 people upvoted that, but `list[1, 2, 3, 4]` is valid Python syntax.

Comment: @wim TIL that it's been added (relatively) recently. But it's syntactically invalid in versions 3.8 and earlier: `TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable`

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the subjective answers one may give to your questions, there are a few mistakes in the code that you present (see the end of this answer).

IMO, `tuple` and `list` are not for constructing tuples and lists by enumerating their elements. To do so, use parentheses and brackets, respectively:

```
t = (1, 2, 3)
l = [1, 2, 3]
```

In fact, when defining a tuple, parentheses are not necessary:

```
t = 1, 2, 3
```

but I think it's much clearer if you use parentheses.

Notice in particular the case of tuples with one element, where it's necessary to use a trailing comma (before the closing parenthesis).

```
t = (42,)
l = [42]
```

It doesn't hurt to do the same for lists and, in general, it doesn't hurt to have a trailing comma both in lists and tuples; but in the case of tuples of one element the comma is necessary.

The usefulness of `tuple` and `list` is for constructing tuples and lists from **other iterables** (generators, tuples, lists, etc.), e.g.

```
t = tuple(i**2 for i in range(10))
l = list(range(100))
```

For lists, list comprehensions are arguably preferable when possible:

```
l1 = list(i**2 for i in range(10))
l2 = [i**2 for i in range(10)]       # this is preferable
```

---

Notice also that there are three lines in your code that are wrong:

1. `mytuple = (myarg)` does not construct a tuple unless `myarg` is already a tuple; these are just parentheses.
2. `mytuple = tuple(1, 2, 3, 4)` raises a `TypeError`.
3. `list[1, 2, 3, 4]` is not a list, just use the brackets (it's funny that this is legal syntax, as mentioned in the comments above, but this is off-topic).

If you insist on using the words `tuple` and `list` when you enumerate the elements, here's (one version of) the correct syntax:

```
t = tuple([1, 2, 3])
l = list([1, 2, 3])
```